# Plotting distribution of multiple measurements in two different groups in R

Tags: r, plot, distribution

I have measurements of approximately 1000 variables in 2 groups with 10 replicates in each, in other words I have 2 dataframes with 10 columns and 1000 rows in each.

I would like to show the distribution of my measurements, in two different groups, to pick up variables that differ significantly between the groups. My initial idea was to do a large scatter plot where the x-coordinate would be an iteration of variables, and the y-coordinate would be measurement, and the points could be color coded. It doesn't quite work as expected however, I get a scatter plot matrix instead.

I tried to go with a boxplot,

```
ratios1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(10000) * 100, 1000, 10))
boxplot(t(log2(ratios1)), horizontal = T)
```

which sort of works but all lines for the boxes makes the plot undecipherable, even for a single group (see figure below). Then I tried to remove the boxes and add the points afterwards as [suggested here](http://www.r-bloggers.com/boxplots-without-boxes/)

```
boxplot(t(log2(ratios1)), horizontal = T, border = "white")
points(t(log2(ratios1)), pch=1)
```

But that didn't quite work either, as I only got the first variable drawn on the graph.

How can I display this type of information?

[image: vertical boxplot]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, columns correspond to variables and rows to observations, not the other way around.

```
set.seed(42)
ratios1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(10000) * 100, 10, 1000))
```

You could plot quantiles like this:

```
library(reshape2)
ratios2 <- melt(ratios1)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(ratios2, aes(x = as.numeric(variable), y = value)) +
  stat_summary(fun.data = function(y) as.data.frame(setNames(as.list(quantile(y, probs = c(0.025, 0.5, 0.975))), c("ymin", "y", "ymax"))), 
               color = "blue") +
  stat_summary(fun.data = function(y) as.data.frame(setNames(as.list(quantile(y, probs = c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75))), c("ymin", "y", "ymax"))), 
               color = "red") +
  xlab("variable")
```

[image: resulting plot]

There are no groups in your data, so I don't know what to do with that. Maybe you could facet by group. However, I don't think this kind of plot would be very useful for your goal of "pick[ing] up variables that differ significantly between the groups". I would do a hypothesis test with the appropriate correction for alpha error inflation.